# How to fix AS3 button?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a problem with my puzzle game as there is an image which appears when a button is pressed. The continue button should go to the next puzzle but it only works when the image is on the screen and when it's not on screen the button does not work.

This is the code for the continue button:

```
continuelvl3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_23);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_24(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    removeChild(Elsa);  
    gotoAndStop(15);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to check if your image exist, so something like this

```
function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_24(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(this.contains(Elsa))removeChild(Elsa);  
    gotoAndStop(15);
}
```

Comment: @M.Vekaria Great, why not accept it as an answer and up vote so it may help people visiting this question in future

Comment: ...and that is why people with reputation of 1 are less likely to get answers